# Woocommerce wordpress functions.php - adding php to div

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I am trying to integrate woocommerce to a non woocommerce theme. It is going fine except for one problem.

My theme has a div called block that hides the content then fades it in/adds padding. I want this to be in the woocommerce pages too.

The div is like this

```
  <div id="block" <?php 
  if ($detect->isMobile()) {if($detect->isTablet()){
  /* Tab */
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$tablet_header_position.'"';};
} else {
  /* Mob */ }
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$mobile_header_position.'"';};
} else {
  /* Desc */
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$header_position.'"';};
} 
?>>&nbsp;</div>
```

Using this http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

I tried to put this into my functions PHP and all I get is a white page and lots of syntax errors

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);
'
function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '

    <div id="block" <?php 
      if ($detect->isMobile()) {if($detect->isTablet()){
      /* Tab */
      if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$tablet_header_position.'"';};
    } else {
      /* Mob */ }
      if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$mobile_header_position.'"';};
    } else {
      /* Desc */
      if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$header_position.'"';};
    } 
    ?>>&nbsp;</div><section id="main">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</section>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted has syntax errors because you are using single quotes within a string that are not escaped.  The code is also attempting to inject PHP which is only possible if the output code is later going to be interpreted by the PHP processor.

There are two ways you can approach this. You can create an output buffer and later send the output through a pipe and processed with an include statement, or by sending it to the php eval function.  Due to the security risks neither of these options should be used.

The following code will probably provide the results you are aiming for without creating a PHP injection security risk.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);
//' Not sure why this quote was here....
function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  //echo ' 

 // ending PHP processor instruction here will cause code to execute when current function is called

 ?>

<div id="block" <?php 
  if ($detect->isMobile()) {if($detect->isTablet()){
  /* Tab */
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_tablet_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$tablet_header_position.'"';};
} else {
  /* Mob */ }
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_mobile_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$mobile_header_position.'"';};
} else {
  /* Desc */
  if (get_field("search_override_header_position", "options") && get_field("search_header_position", "options")) {echo 'data-header-position="'.get_field("search_header_position", "options").'"';} else {echo 'data-header-position="'.$header_position.'"';};
} 
?>>&nbsp;</div><section id="main"><?php 

// '; // no need for ending quote here but we do need to reopen the PHP processor instruction that we closed above instead of using an echo
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
    echo '</section>';
}
```